# How can i get blocks in linear which have different height and not get blank space under longer blocks in html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to create a grid , which contains small blocks of fixed width, so only 3 box can be placed per row.

i am using this http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-3-col-portfolio/

but if i increase image height of 1 element , then there gets the blank space under other box which have less height and they dont get in linear .

they look just like this.

[image]

So how can i make them stick to one below another having only fixed width but variable height ?

Comment: you could use a plugin like isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: thanks looking into it i want something very lightweight.,

Comment: there's is no easy lightwieght way to re-invent the layout engine of html/css. you can use min-height and overflow to make it look less crappy with no JS ;)